# Username alignment issue in Recent Badges section

Tags: bug, design

In the Recent Badges section on Code Review, I've found this entry:

[image]

I don't recall seeing that happen before, so I assume it has to do with the recent design change.

OS: Windows 7
Browser: Chrome 41.0.2272.89 m

Comment: [status-reproduced] on Chromium 40.0.2214.111, Ubuntu 14.04. It's just that the username is too long, causing it to wrap to the next line (no place for a word break either). There's probably a better / less confusing way of showing this, though.

Comment: @Doorknob: It looks like the badge length applies, too.  If you look at that page now (it doesn't update too quickly), some usernames are about the same length.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's a combination of long badge name and long username. It might be better if the top margin of the username was reduced and bottom margin increased, to more clearly show which badge it corresponds to.